# VBA to Match, Copy Row, then Paste in a Column without blank cells from ComboBox value

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a workbook that I use for delivery notes, sheet1 is the delivery note template and sheet2 is customer name and address data. There is an ActiveX ComboBox on sheet1 which is populated with the client names so when I select a client this brings up the their name and address in the delivery note template, cells [C5:C11]. I have code for the combobox and this works fine but in more than 70% of despatches I need to edit the address details because of different areas, departments or buildings etc so this macro I am using is now a waste of time because I cannot edit the data. I do not want to finish up with a database of 300 addresses when perhaps 60 will do the job. So I think the solution is to copy and paste the data which will then allow editing. I have tried to edit my existing code to make it copy and paste but keep getting various errors so would appreciate any help or new ideas.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
' CopyNameAddress Macro
    Dim strCustomer As String
    Dim iRow As String
    Dim rngDetails As Range
    strCustomer = ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)
With ThisWorkbook
    With .Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    iRow = Application.Match(strCustomer, .Range("B3:B" & .Range("B" & .Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), 0) + 2
            Set rngDetails = .Range("C" & iRow & ":H" & iRow).Select
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
            Selection.Cop
        End With
    With .Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`With`s aren't nestable (at least the higher ones aren't active). You can only have one active at a time.

For such a small script `with` gives no advantages. It's good in loops and when setting many properties on an object.

The error message text is *"Expected End With"*

Comment: With *is* nestable.  Try it.

Comment: Hi Tim, Tried your code but get error 1004 - "Unable to get the SpecialCells property of the range class"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
' CopyNameAddress Macro
    Dim strCustomer As String
    Dim iRow As String
    Dim rngDetails As Range

    strCustomer = ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)

    With ThisWorkbook

        With .Sheets("Sheet2") '<< no .Select
            iRow = Application.Match(strCustomer, _
            .Range("B3:B" & .Range("B" & .Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), 0) + 2
            Set rngDetails = .Range("C" & iRow & ":H" & iRow) '<< no .Select
            'you can copy without selecting...
            rngDetails.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Copy '<< you had ".Cop" here
        End With

        With .Sheets("Sheet1") 'no .Select
            'missed the leading period on the next line (and there's no need to Select)
            .Range("C5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                         SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```